# Will shift left set the carry flag to 0 or 1?

Tags: assembly, x86

If i have a binary value of 10000001 in cl and i execute the following command `shl cl,2` (x86) will the carry flag be set to 1 or 0?

im a little confused since the last number to "fall off" was a 0 however we are losing data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between SHL and SAL in 80x86](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373415/difference-between-shl-and-sal-in-80x86)

Comment: @MikeW that doesn't actually address this question, as far as I can tell

Comment: After your edit, you're not losing anything anymore. Don't you mean `cl`? Otherwise this question doesn't actually ask what it's asking, so to speak.

Comment: @Harold First answer to that question specifically refers to what happens to Carry.

Comment: @MikeW ok I suppose it does - but sort of accidentally, it's really about something else.

Comment: Shift inevitably loses data. So does AND and OR :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr) explicitly says:

> At the end of the shift operation, the CF flag contains the last bit shifted out of the destination operand.

The other bits don't matter. They're just gone.